# alignment not showing up correctly on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having an issue with wordpress where I am aligning logos using the text widget. When I build the html and css locally or on jsfiddle, it works perfectly but when I try to replicate it on wordpress it comes out funny. Here is the site  [Logos on the write hand side](http://www.taranoone.ie/about-tara/) and here is the code I am using [jsfiddle of code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmmfj0mw/).

Could someone tell me what I need to do to make it look the same on wordpress as it does on the fiddle (I.E Two columns of logos)

```
<!doctype html>        
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Put in title</title>
        <style>
            .association_logos_container_left 
            {
                max-width:140px;
                float:right;
            }
            .association_logos_container_left .association_logos_left img
            {
                max-width:100px;
                float:left;
                margin: 5px;
                display:block;  
            }  
            .association_logos_container_right {
                max-width:140px;
                float:right;
            }
            .association_logos_container_right .association_logos_right img
            {
                max-width:100px;
                float:right;
                margin: 5px;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>    
<body>




     <div class="association_logos_container_left">

        <div class="association_logos_left"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/TUSLA-logo.jpeg" alt="Tusla"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_left"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Turning-Point-logo.png" alt="Turning Point"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_left"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Parenting-plus.jpeg" alt="Parenting Plus"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_left"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Living-life-logo.jpeg" alt="Living life"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_left"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Incredible-years.jpeg" alt="Incredible Years"></div>
    </div>     
    <div class="association_logos_container_right">


        <div class="association_logos_right"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/IACP-logo.jpeg" alt="IACP"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_right"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/HSE-Logo.jpeg" alt="HSE Logo"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_right"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DIT-logo.jpeg" alt="DIT Logo"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_right"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DCU-logo.jpeg" alt="DCU Logo"></div>
        <div class="association_logos_right"><img src="http://www.taranoone.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Crawford-Art-College-logo.jpeg" alt="Crawford Art College"></div>

     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you using a theme that may have a default padding or margin that is throwing it off?

Comment: I dont think it is that as they are displaying with two in a row but just not correctly

Comment: You're missing `.association_logos_container_left  { max-width:140px;  float:right;  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this at end of your CSS file

```
.association_logos_container_left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.association_logos_container_right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 140px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Or you can just add this

```
.association_logos_container_left {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Nenad. I have tried that and it didnt fully work. However it has isolated the problem further. Using inspect element I can see that the right container is behaving correctly but the left container does not seem to be encapsulating the divs so they are being jumbled. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to just add this at end of you `CSS` file `.association_logos_container_left {
    display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: Thanks. I included it within the first .association_logos_container but it worked when I put it at the end (?).

Comment: Yea CSS reads from top to bottom so last will override previous code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.association_logos_container_left {
  float: left;
}

.association_logos_container_right {
  float: right;
}
```